# Replace square brackets + contents with the contents as a mergefield

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to change the contents of square brackets into a merge field. I've got 80-ish documents to go through some with none square brackets and some with a few (none nested).

I have managed to run my code and it has worked for some files. Others (majority) have given an overflow error. When I examined what was happening in one of the files, the code picks up the contents correctly, it just puts the merge field in the wrong place which in turn causes it to keep finding the same set of square brackets.

```
Public Function searchFiles(fFile As Variant, rootFolderStr2 As String, rootFolderStr As String)
    Dim strTemp As String, mfc As String, msg As String
    Dim startStr As Integer, endStr As Integer
    Dim objWord As New Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    Dim aField As Field, fFolder As String
    Dim rng As Variant, myField As Field, oldField As Variant

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    'open file
    'Open fFile For Input As #1
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(fFile)
    objDoc.TrackRevisions = False
    strTemp = objDoc.Range(0, objDoc.Range.End)

    startStr = InStrRev(strTemp, "[")
    endStr = InStrRev(strTemp, "]")

    Do While startStr <> 0
        'Merge field contents
        mfc = Right(Left(strTemp, endStr - 1), endStr - startStr - 1)
        Set rng = objDoc.Range(startStr - 1, endStr)
        Set myField = objDoc.Fields.Add(Range:=rng, Type:=wdFieldMergeField, Text:=mfc)

        strTemp = objDoc.Range(0, objDoc.Range.End)

        'Find next merge field
        startStr = InStrRev(strTemp, "[")
        endStr = InStrRev(strTemp, "]")
        If endStr < startStr And endStr <> -1 Then
            msg = "Error occured in " & fileName & " " & startStr & " " & endStr
            Debug.Print (msg)
            startStr = 0
            endStr = 0
        End If
    Loop
    'put in right folder
    fFolder = Right(objDoc.FullName, Len(objDoc.FullName) - Len(rootFolderStr))

    objDoc.SaveAs fileName:=rootFolderStr2 & "\" & fFolder
    objDoc.Close
    objWord.Quit

ErrorHandler:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Debug.Print ("Error occured in file: " & fileName & " " & Err.Description)
    Exit Function
End If

End Function
```

I'm struggling to understand how the objects in word work so forgive, please.

Any answers as to what's causing this problem would be appreciated or any help with methods to do this in a better manner.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub UpdateDocuments()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, strDocNm As String, wdDoc As Document
strDocNm = ActiveDocument.FullName
strFolder = GetFolder
If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc", vbNormal)
While strFile <> ""
  If strFolder & "\" & strFile <> strDocNm Then
    Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
      Call MakeFields(wdDoc)
      wdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=True
  End If
  strFile = Dir()
Wend
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
Dim oFolder As Object
GetFolder = ""
Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function

Sub MakeFields(wdDoc As Document)
With wdDoc.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "\[*\]"
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    .Characters.First.Text = vbNullString
    .Characters.Last.Text = vbNullString
    .Fields.Add Range:=.Duplicate, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="MERGEFIELD " & .Text, Preserveformatting:=False
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
End Sub
```

The above code processes all documents in the selected folder.

Answer (score -1):

OK.  The generic advice is to always, always, always put option explicit as the start of your module or class.  This helps highlights errors in your code related misuse of syntax and undeclared variables etc.  In your posted code there is one undeclared variable 'Filename'.

When working with Word it is always better to try to find a way of working with the word object model rather than extracting text.

You can modify your existing code by replacing the instrrev with the .MoveStart/EndUntil methods.

I've updated your code to use these move methods.

If you don't understand what a keyword does then place your cursor on it and press F1.  This will take you to the MS help page.  For the Word object model the help pages need careful reading.

```
Option Explicit

' Changed to sub as you are not returning any values
Public Sub searchFiles(fFile As Variant, rootFolderStr2 As String, rootFolderStr As String)

Const FieldOpen                     As String = "["
Const FieldClose                    As String = "]"

    Dim strTemp As String, mfc As String, msg As String

    Dim objWord As New Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    ' Dim aField As FieldDim
    Dim fFolder As String
    ' Dim rng As Variant
    ' Dim myField As Field
    ' Dim oldField As Variant

    ' Not previously declared
    Dim Filename As String


    Dim SearchRng                   As Word.Range
    Dim FieldRng                    As Word.Range
    Dim Moved                       As Long
    'open file
    'Open fFile For Input As #1
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(fFile)
    objDoc.TrackRevisions = False

    'strTemp = objDoc.Range(0, objDoc.Range.End)
    Set SearchRng = ActiveDocument.Content

    'startStr = InStrRev(strTemp, "[")
    Moved = SearchRng.MoveStartUntil(cset:=FieldOpen)

    'Do While startStr <> 0
    Do Until Moved = 0
        'Merge field contents
        'mfc = Right(Left(strTemp, endStr - 1), endStr - startStr - 1)
        FieldRng.Start = SearchRng.Start + 1

        'endStr = InStrRev(strTemp, "]")
        ' exit if we don't find a closing field marker
        ' The side effect (which we want) is that the end is also moved
        If SearchRng.MoveEndUntil(cset:=FieldClose) = 0 Then GoTo ErrorHandler
        FieldRng.End = SearchRng.End + 1

        ' reduce the FieldRng to just the text
        FieldRng.Characters.First.Delete
        FieldRng.Characters.Last.Delete

        'Set rng = objDoc.Range(startStr - 1, endStr
        'Set myField = objDoc.Fields.Add(Range:=rng, Type:=wdFieldMergeField, Text:=mfc)
        objDoc.Fields.Add Range:=FieldRng, Type:=wdFieldMergeField, Text:=FieldRng.Text

        'strTemp = objDoc.Range(0, objDoc.Range.End)
        ' We now need to move the start of the search range to after the mergefield
        SearchRng.Start = FieldRng.End + 1

        'Find next merge field
        'startStr = InStrRev(strTemp, "[")
        'endStr = InStrRev(strTemp, "]")
        Moved = SearchRng.MoveStartUntil(cset:=FieldOpen)
'        If endStr < startStr And endStr <> -1 Then
'            msg = "Error occured in " & Filename & " " & startStr & " " & endStr
'            Debug.Print (msg)
'            startStr = 0
'            endStr = 0
'        End If
    Loop
    'put in right folder
    fFolder = Right(objDoc.FullName, Len(objDoc.FullName) - Len(rootFolderStr))

    objDoc.SaveAs Filename:=rootFolderStr2 & "\" & fFolder
    objDoc.Close
    objWord.Quit

ErrorHandler:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Debug.Print ("Error occured in file: " & Filename & " " & Err.Description)
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

The code above compiles without error but I haven't testing the logic.  I'll leave that as 'an exercise for the reader'